# Compute $E^{\mathbb{Q}} \left[ \exp(S_T) | \mathcal{F}_t \right] $ with exponential Vasicek Model (1978)

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

Please show me how to solve (3) with computation processes. (1) and (2) were initial questions which I solved. I show the answers (1) and (2) below.

---

(1) Solve the S.D.E.
\begin{eqnarray}
dS_t=\alpha S_t dt + \sigma dB_t
\end{eqnarray}
in terms of $\alpha, \sigma >0$, and the initial condition $S_0$.

(2) For which values $\alpha_M$ of $\alpha$ is the discount price process $\tilde{S}_t = e^{-rt} S_t$, $t \in [0, T]$, a martingale under $\mathbb{P}$?

(3) Compute the arbitrage price 
\begin{eqnarray}
C(t, S_t)=e^{-r(T-t)} E^{\mathbb{Q}} \left[ \exp(S_T) | \mathcal{F}_t \right]
\end{eqnarray}
at time $t \in [0, T]$ of the contingent claim $\exp(S_T)$, with $\alpha=\alpha_M$.

---

(1) My Answer

- Let $f(t, x)=e^{-\alpha t} x$, use Itô's formula.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  d e^{-\alpha t} S_t &=& -\alpha e^{-\alpha t} S_t dt + e^{-\alpha t} d S_t + \frac{1}{2} 0 d[S_t] \\
  &=& e^{-\alpha t}  \left( -\alpha S_t dt +\alpha S_t dt + \sigma dB_t \right) \\
  &=& \sigma  e^{-\alpha t}  dB_t \\
  \int^t_0 d e^{-\alpha s} S_s &=& \int^t_0 \sigma  e^{-\alpha s}  dB_s \\
  %e^{-\alpha t} S_t -S_0 &=& \int^t_0 \sigma  e^{-\alpha s}  dB_s \\
  S_t &=& e^{\alpha t} \left( S_0  + \sigma \int^t_0  e^{-\alpha s}  dB_s \right) 
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

(2) My Answer

- The following formula shows that the risk-free interest rate $ r $ is the discount rate for the question, and is $ \alpha_M = \alpha = r $.
  \begin{eqnarray}
  \tilde{S}_t = e^{-rt} S_t = e^{-\alpha t} S_t ＝S_0  + \sigma \int^t_0  e^{-\alpha s}  dB_s 
  \end{eqnarray}

$\square$

(3) Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, express $S_T$ in terms of $S_t$, which can be obtained from your solution in (1)

\begin{eqnarray}
S_T &=& e^{\alpha T} \left( S_0  + \sigma \int^t_0  e^{-\alpha s}  dB_s + \sigma \int^T_t  e^{-\alpha s}  dB_s\right) \\
&=&e^{\alpha (T-t)}S_t + \sigma \int^T_t  e^{\alpha (T-s)} dB_s
\end{eqnarray}

Next, evaluate the expectation,
\begin{eqnarray}
E_t\left[\exp{(S_T)}\right] &=& \exp\left(e^{\alpha (T-t)}S_t\right) E_t\left[ \exp\left(\sigma \int^T_t  e^{\alpha (T-s)} dB_s\right)\right] \\
&=& \exp\left(e^{\alpha (T-t)}S_t\right)\exp\left(\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 \int^T_t  e^{2\alpha (T-s)} ds\right) \\
&=& \exp\left[e^{\alpha (T-t)}S_t + \frac{\sigma^2}{4a}(e^{2a(T-t)}-1) \right]
\end{eqnarray}

Finally, the answer to (3) is

$$C(t,S_t) = \exp\left[-r(T-t) + \frac{\sigma^2}{4a}(e^{2a(T-t)}-1) +e^{\alpha (T-t)}S_t \right] $$

Comment: Thank you for giving me the real genius proof in a short time. I assume you used below formula. Please tell me whether my understanding is correct or not. 

\begin{eqnarray}
E \left[ \exp \left( \int^T_0 f(s) dB_s \right) |F_t \right] &=& \exp \left( \int^t_0 f(s) dB_s + \frac{1}{2} \int^T_t \left(  f(s)  \right)^2 ds \right) \\
E \left[ \exp \left( \int^T_t f(s) dB_s \right) |F_t \right] &=& \exp \left( \frac{1}{2} \int^T_t \left(  f(s)  \right)^2 ds \right) 
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Correct. They are used in evaluating $E_t[\exp{S_T}]$.